# How to query the current user from the database - Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am currently in a fix and need your help. I am working on an API using Django_rest_framework and currently on tthe registration module. The code below is a feature that regenerate OTP and send to the current user. However, I can't access the current user, but i have his details in the database..eg: phone_nuumber, is_active=False, is_verified=False. I want to be able to access the user using his phone number then regennerate OTP and send to his phone number after the OTP expires.

```
# regenerate OTP
class RegenerateOTP(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="This endpoint is responsible for regenerating OTP if expired",
        operation_description="This endpoint regenerate OTP after expiration period",
    )
    def post(self, request):
        instance = CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=False).first()
        if int(instance.max_otp_try) == 0 and timezone.now() < instance.otp_max_out:
            return Response(
                "Max OTP try reached, try after an hour.",
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        otp = generateRandomOTP(100000, 999999)
        otp_expire = timezone.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)
        max_otp_try = int(instance.max_otp_try) - 1

        instance.otp = otp
        instance.otp_expire = otp_expire
        instance.max_otp_try = max_otp_try

        if max_otp_try == 0:
            instance.otp_max_out = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
        elif max_otp_try == -1:
            instance.max_otp_try = settings.MAX_OTP_TRY
        else:
            instance.otp_max_out = None
            instance.max_otp_try = max_otp_try
        instance.save()
        send_otp(instance.phone_number, otp)
        return Response(
            "successfully re-generated the new otp", status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

I have tried saving the user's phone_number when registering in session or cache so I can always get it back using in this view by doing:

```
phone_number = request.session.get('phone_number) and then pass it on to,
instance = CustomUser.objects.filter(phone_number=phone_number).first()
```

My problem noww is that I understand this is not a better way of implementing it wit scale at the back of my mind. I need a better way to solve this challenge please. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `and send to the current user` vs `CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=False).first()` - I'm afraid this is _a random_ user.

Comment: yes, which is why I want to get the phone number of the user that's regenerating the OTP instead of a random user. @Ivan Starostin

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `phone_number` field in `CustomUser` as unique, and the use `CustomUser.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)`. You should set it as unique since you want to get access to a specific user through the phone number. Phone numbers shouldn't repeat themselves anyways.

That'll be better than what you currently have.

Comment: yes, the phone number is unique but it's not a parameter in the RegenerateOTPView which is why I am having the issue.

Comment: Didn't you say that you saved it in cache?

Comment: Yes, I did save it in the session but is that a better way to implement it because I read somewhere that sessions have it drawbacks especially where there are too many requests. so I am looking for a better way to handle such a scenario.

Comment: why don't you use a form for it? that way, if the user needs another otp, they will have to click on something saying "re-send" for example. Then the form will be sent, and you can have the phone number inside the request, and can do what I recommended initially. You can stop the reloading of the page with JS, with event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

Why did you need the current user to send the OTP? Is the opt needed for registration? if OTP is needed for registration, don't fetch the user from DB. Just get the phone number and send the OTP to this phone number. If you need the current user to send OTP then make the phone_number field unique in the table  and make **db_index=True** & use `CustomUser.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)`,
don't use the **filter** on this because **filter** are much more expensive than **get** and also use **try catch** block to get the current user.

Comment: Actually, this is the flow of the application:
The user provides a phone number on registration first and an OTP is sent to that phone number to verify the user. If the phone number is verified, he can proceed to other parts of the registration which include getting other details of the user.

Comment: However, due to network or something, he is unable to get the OTP during verification, he will need to request for OTP again which is another endpoint and doesn't have the phone number as a parameter/field but already his phone number is saved in the database as active=Fallse and is_verified=False. The phone number is unique in the CustomUser. @Joaquin

Comment: you can store the phone number is session, and if the phone number is verified then clear the session. And if the user request for the top second time, then get the phone number from session. Here is the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I did this but the challenge now how the clientside/frontend can implement it using react.

Comment: on the client side, client can store it in cookies or local storage